# Map an arry of inputs to another array

Tags: arrays, c

Hello i am trying to do a program where i receive 14 inputs and then map them on a grid(which is one 2d array) my problem now is that i can't figure out how to map the multiple inputs.
On another problem i fixed this by using switch, but in this one i don't see that workning here.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 
int main () {
        int linhas = 5;
        int colunas = 6;
        char tabela[5][6];
        char pecas[] = {'R','r','P','P','P','P','P','P','p','p','p','p','p','p'}; ;
        char *coordenada[13][2];
        int i,j;
        memset (tabela, '.', sizeof tabela);
        i=0;
        j=0;
        while(i!=14){
            scanf("%s", coordenada[i]);
            printf("Peca[%d]=%c e coordenada[%d]=%s\n \n",i,pecas[i],i,coordenada[i]);
            i++;
        }
       for (int count = 5, p = 0; p < linhas; p++, count--)
        {
            printf ("%d:", count);
            for (int o = 0; o < colunas; o++)
                {
                printf ("%c", tabela[p][o]);
                }
            printf ("\n");
            }
            printf ("  abcdef");
}
```

additionally im getting these errors:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:21: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
             scanf("%s", coordenada[i]);
                     ^
main.c:22:51: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 5 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
             printf("Peca[%d]=%c e coordenada[%d]=%s\n \n",i,pecas[i],i,coordenada[i]);
                                                   ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your input look like? Since you've mangled the declaration of `coordenada`, I'll have to guess that you intended it to be `char coordenada[13][2]` and are wanting to store 13 strings of length 1.  If so, you should use `scanf("%1s")`  If you want it to be 2 strings of length 12, you could us `scanf("%12s")`.  Either way, you definitely do not want to use `"%s"` with no width specifier, and you need to fix the declaration.

Comment: Hello Wiliam yes,i want to store 13 strings of length 1.

Comment: My input should be like "a1"(enter)"f1"(enter)"d1"(enter) so on and so forth.

Comment: "f1" is a string of length 2, and you would need an array of size 3 to hold it.  If you want to input 13 strings, why are you iterating from 0 to 13?  (That iterates 14 times).

Comment: Sorry, i need 14 strings. I should receive 14 inputs, so thats why i am iterating 14 times.My bad.

Comment: Seems like (for a start), you want `char coordenada[14][3]`;

Comment: And `scanf("%2s ", coordenada[i]);` (Note the `2` and the space after the `s`)

Comment: Wouldn't that give me an array of 15 or does the first one not count, im sorry for im am a beginner.

Comment: `a[N]` gives an array of size N.  Why would it give an array of size N + 1?  A char array of size N can hold a string of length N - 1.  Since `a` has size N, the valid indices are `0` to `N - 1`.  Attempting to access `a[N]` is an error.

Comment: Okay, thanks.
But how do i convert the input into the array positions, that's bugging me a lot because i don't seem to grasp the logic of it, and i have searched far and wide.
Any tips on how i should approach this problem?